# Microsoft Edge Authentication popup

Tags: angular7, windows-authentication, jwt, .net-core-2.2

I have configured .net core 2.2 API to use windows and JWT authentication both:

```
 "windowsAuthentication": true, 
 "anonymousAuthentication": true,
```

The application has angular as an SPA on the UI. Now the application works perfectly fine with chrome, however on edge, it keeps showing the credential popup and I am not able to remove it.
I have configured site also on the security tab for internet options as *.abc.com so that all such URLs are trusted.

The failed network call shows that edge removes the bearer token and replaces it with negotiate, which causes the 401 and then popup.

what will I be missing ?

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who has faced the same issue, in the end I have split the project in two projects, one with windows authentication, and other with JWT authentication only.

Only this solved the problem.